# getting value from a cookie in SELECT statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i am trying to retreive a cookie value on a SELECT sql statement , here is my code

```
      SELECT orders.order_id, orders.order_date, orders.payment_type, 
    orders.cardnumber, packages.Package_name, orders.package_id,
 packages.package_price 
    FROM orders INNER JOIN packages ON orders.package_id = packages.Package_ID 
    WHERE (orders.username = '**value here**')
```

i need to retreive the value of the cookie in `orders.username = '**value here**'`

my cookie is : `Request.Cookies["Username"].Value`

Answer (score 3):

Use a parameterized query, with the value of the cookie being the passed in parameter.

```
string sql = "SELECT orders.order_id, 
                orders.order_date, 
                orders.payment_type, 
                orders.cardnumber, 
                packages.Package_name, 
                orders.package_id, 
                packages.package_price 
              FROM orders INNER JOIN packages ON orders.package_id = packages.Package_ID 
              WHERE (orders.username = @UserName)"

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a parameterized SQL statement, specifying the parameter value separately from the SQL itself.

The documentation for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) gives an example.